# Error "sslv3 alert handshake failure" using Net::SMTP::TLS

Tags: perl, ssl, starttls

I'm trying to send email with Perl. My code works fine with Yahoo's SMTP server but when I try to use another SMTP server (with a self-signed SSL certificate), I get this error:

> Couldn't start TLS: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
>    at mail2.pl line 2.

My code is:

```
use Net::SMTP::TLS;

my $mailer = new Net::SMTP::TLS(
        'mail.SomeHost.com',
        Hello   =>      'mail.SomeHost.com',
        Port    =>      587,
        User    =>      'info@SomeHost.com',
        Password=>      '123456789'
);

$mailer->mail('info@SomeHost.com');
$mailer->to('info@SomeHost.com');
$mailer->data();
$mailer->datasend("From: info@SomeHost.com\n");
$mailer->datasend("To: info@SomeHost.com\n");
$mailer->datasend("Subject: test\n");
$mailer->datasend("Content-type: text/html\n\n");
$mailer->datasend("\n");
$mailer->datasend("<html><body><p>hi text</p><br></body></html>\n");
$mailer->dataend();
$mailer->quit;
```

How can I fix this?

Result with `-MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4`:

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2537: new ctx 17003088
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1343: start handshake
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:553: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:589: not using SNI because hostname is unknown
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:621: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:640: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=5
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:663: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:693: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:653: Net::SSLeay::connect -> 0
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:701: connection failed - connect returned 0
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1769: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:1774: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems
    error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2570: free ctx 17003088 open=17003088
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2575: free ctx 17003088 callback
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2582: OK free ctx 17003088 Couldn't start TLS:
    SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems
    error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake
failure  at mail2.pl line 2.
```

Comment: Check if server still supports Sslv3. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385603/facebook-sdk-for-php-error-curlexception-35-error14094410ssl-routinesssl3

Comment: Net::SMTP::TLS had its last release 2008. It works only with current IO::Socket::SSL version if you either patched Net::SMTP::TLS  (because of a bug in setting SSL_version) or worked around the bugs by patching IO::Socket::SSL. The latter is done often wrong which causes new errors. I recommend to use a current version of Net::SMTP (version 3.x) which has proper support for SSL. If you cannot do this run your code with `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 ...` to get detailed information about the SSL handshake and add the output to your question.

Comment: unfortunately i can't use NET::SMTP and i must use NET::SMTP::TLS , and i was edited SSL.pm.

Comment: ok i added result with "perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4"

Comment: @user3001228: strange error, SSL handshake was not successful but was shutdown in an ordered way. It would be helpful if you could provide the server you are trying to access and the version of IO::Socket::SSL so one could try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do a packet capture using tcpdump and look at the TLS messages using tshark or wireshark.

Comment: @user3001228: and since you changed SSL.pm it would be good to know which changes you did, because like I said the problem is really Net::SMTP::TLS and some of the published workarounds for SSL.pm actually cause harm instead of fixing the problem. The problem might already be solved once you apply the fix to the correct place (i.e. Net::SMTP::TLS) instead and restore SSL.pm to the original version.