# Send mail through Gmail using Perl

Tags: bash, perl, email

I have this perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::SMTP::TLS;

my $file="/var/www/myweb/textfile.txt";

my $smtp = new Net::SMTP::TLS(
'smtp.gmail.com',
    Hello => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    Port => 587,
    User => 'mymail@gmail.com',
    Password => 'mypassword',
);

$smtp->mail('mymail@gmail.com');
$smtp->to('destinationmail@hotmail.com');
$smtp->data();
$smtp->datasend("Subject: Subject of mail \n");
$smtp->datasend("\n");

#make sure file exists
if (-e $file) {
    $smtp->datasend("body of the mail");
    #read the file one line at a time
    open( RFILE, "<$file" )||print "could not open file";
    while (my $line  = <RFILE>){
            $smtp->datasend("$line");
    }
    close(RFILE) || print "could not close file";
}
else {
    #print "did not find the report $file ";
    exit 1;
}
#End the message.
$smtp->dataend();
#Close the connection to your server.
$smtp->quit();
```

This script open the textfile.txt and put its content in an email body. Since yesterday, this script was working fine in 4 different Linux computers. Now it returns this message:

> Couldn't start TLS: SSL connect attempt failed because of handshake problems
>   error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol
>   version at scriptname.pl line 7

I have not found any documentation about any change on Gmail SMTP service. How can I do?

Thanks

Comment: [related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34455133/error-sslv3-alert-handshake-failure-using-netsmtptls),[also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385603/facebook-sdk-for-php-error-curlexception-35-error14094410ssl-routinesssl3),[also](http://openssl.6102.n7.nabble.com/TLS-ALERT-PROTOCOL-VERSION-Error-td12978.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I choose to change a little the script. Instead of Net::SMTP::TLS, I have used MIME::Lite

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use MIME::Lite;
use Net::SMTPS;

my $file="/var/www/myweb/myfile.txt";
open(FILE, $file) or die "Can't read file 'filename' [$!]\n";  
$document = <FILE>; 
close (FILE);  
my $msg = MIME::Lite ->new (  
From => 'sender@hotmail.com',
To => 'recipient@hotmail.com',
Subject => 'mail subject',  
Data => qq{
<body>
Text message body HTML format. <p> $document </p>
</body>
},
Type => 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'
);  
my $USERNAME = 'sender@hotmail.com';
my $PASSWORD = 'password'; 

my $smtps = Net::SMTPS->new("smtp.live.com", Port => 587, doSSL=> 'starttls', SSL_version=>'TLSv1');

$smtps->auth ( $USERNAME, $PASSWORD ) or DIE("Could not authenticate with mail.\n");

$smtps ->mail('sender@hotmail.com');  
$smtps->to('recipient@hotmail.com');
$smtps->data(); 
$smtps->datasend( $msg->as_string() );  
$smtps->dataend();  
$smtps->quit;
```

I use Outlook.com service instead of GMail.

Thank you!

Comment: "Instead of Net::SMTP::TLS, I have used MIME::Lite" - this is wrong. You have replaced Net::SMTP::TLS with Net::SMTPS. You use MIME::Lite only to construct the message but not to send it. The sending is then done with Net::SMTPS and could have been done with (a recent version of) Net::SMTP too as I proposed. In fact, Net::SMTPS just uses Net::SMTP but adds the TLS stuff for older versions of Net::SMTP which did not include it, similar to Net::SSLGlue.

Answer (score 4):

[Net::SMTP::TLS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP::TLS) is unmaintained since 2006 and has bugs which make it impossible to use with current versions of IO::Socket::SSL (due to more strict checking of given parameters) and with current sites (due to preference for SSL 3.0). These bugs can be fixed by modifying Net::SMTP::TLS or can be worked around by modifying IO::Socket::SSL (which is the wrong thing to do, but there are enough sites which propagate this).

My guess is that you've tried to use this module and made some changes either to make it work, either by modifying Net::SMTP::TLS or by modifying IO::Socket::SSL. And due to some updates part of these modifications are gone now. Due to the nature of the bugs this might cause you to try SSL 3.0 which is not support by gmail.

My recommendation: throw Net::SMTP::TLS far far away and use Net::SMTP (core module). The recent versions 3.x (release 2014) support TLS and IPv6 natively (if IO::Socket::SSL is installed). It is included with perl 5.22+.  If you cannot use the newest version you can install [Net::SSLGlue::SSL](https://metacpan.org/release/Net-SSLGlue) which make using SSL with older versions of Net::SMTP possible.

Comment: If I change Net::SMTP::TLS to Net::SMTP, all syntax of script also changes. I don't know how it works Is there any example so I can see how it works? Thank you

Comment: @Xuti: since the interface of Net::SMTP::TLS was designed after the interface of Net::SMTP you should probably not need to change anything apart from the module name. But you need to add a call to `$smtp->starttls` right after you've created the object. For more information have a look [at the documentation for Net::SMTP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SMTP).

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
and make sure is "Turn on"

Comment: Hello, Yes, it is turned on. Thank you!

Comment: This advice would help with SMTP authorization errors but not with TLS protocol errors.