# Paypal ssl handshake faliure

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

Hi I am using Paypal PHP SDK to communicate with Paypal Api.

2 days before every thing was working fine. But now I am getting this error on my development servers.

> error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

I am using the following CURL options while requesting:

```
public static $DEFAULT_CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 1,
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,   // maximum number of seconds to allow cURL functions to execute
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'PayPal-PHP-SDK',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => array(),
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1',
);
```

This problem only occuring using SANDBOX mode on live mode every thing works fine.

Any body knows why this is happening?

Thank You

Comment: May be these links can help you....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385603/facebook-sdk-for-php-error-curlexception-35-error14094410ssl-routinesssl3

2..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379773/paypal-ipn-acknowledgements-failing-with-ssl-routinesssl3-read-bytessslv3-aler

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced the same error. It's due to recent updates that PayPal have made: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ1766

You can fix it by adding this to your CURL options:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 1);`

or

`CURLOPT_SSL_SSLVERSION => 1`

EDIT: Complete working settings

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION , 1);
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You for your reply but I have already tried this. I think according to the link you have given I have to update my server.

Comment: I'm not sure that you, try removing this: CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST => 'TLSv1' and adding CURLOPT_SSL_SSLVERSION => 1